# How to add image in to HTML from different folder

Tags: html, css, image

I want to add highlighted image into my HTML file. But my HTML file is in a different folder. I am using VS:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- image add here -->
    <img src="    " alt="">
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sir you can drag the image from the folder to the chrome tab.
now in the search bar you will see a link of that image  use it in the

```
<img src=" paste the link here   " alt="">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files

** i think this url will work for you**

```
<img src="../images/image-victor.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

use ./ or ../ then you will see your folder list

Answer (score 0):

Use `./` to refer current directory. use `../` to refer from the parent directory.

In your example you should use `../` so, it `src="../images/image-victor.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

sir in your case you can use

```css
<img src="/images/image-victor.jpg" alt="image">
```

it would take you to the base parent directory of "My" i.e final and then go to "images" and further select "image-victor.jpg"